# The hybris extension is skipped, during Initialization. How to debug and resolve it?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

Initially all the Extensions were imported. But after some modifications (and tried to initialize), i am facing below issue.

[image]

Question: is how to debug it and fix the issue?

**Edited:**
As per suggestion of @Mafick.
i tried to update "sapbusinessagreementaddon"  extension through hac. i found the cms-responsive-content_zh_CN.impex file( which was throwing the exception).

please find the code below:

**cms-responsive-content_zh_CN.impex**

```
$contentCatalog=powertoolsContentCatalog
$contentCV=catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=$contentCatalog:Staged]
$jarResourceCms=jar:com.sap.hybris.sapbusinessagreementaddon.constants.SapbusinessagreementaddonConstants&/sapbusinessagreementaddon/import/cockpit/cmscockpit
$contentCatalogName=Powertools Content Catalog
$addonExtensionName=sapbusinessagreementaddon
$lang=zh_CN

# update linkname

UPDATE CMSLinkComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];linkName[lang=$lang]
;;BusinessAgreementsLink;"商业协议"
```

**The error thrown in the hac is: as below**

**UPDATE CMSLinkComponent;catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=powertoolsContentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=powertoolsContentCatalog:Staged][unique=true];uid[unique=true];linkName[lang=zh_CN]**

,8796103869500,,,column 3: cannot resolve value '商业协议' for attribute 'linkName' because: cannot find language for value 'zh_CN';;BusinessAgreementsLink;商业协议

**Conclusion:**
As per the issue it cannot resolve "zh_CN" (linkName[lang]). So how can i resolve this issue? Where should i specify lang(zh_CN) to find the language by hybris?
Such that it execute's impex successfully.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see this happens while you are importing '**project data**'.

So go into your hybris admin console (/hac) -> Update and deselect all checkboxes and only activate `sapbusinessagreementaddon` below in project data. Than have a look on the console.

**UPDATE**

Have a look in to this impex file

`/projects/hybris/custom/xxxinitialdata/resources/xxxinitialdata/import/coredata/common/essential-data.impex`

There you can define your Languages. Add here your missing language

Answer (score 0):

You probably have errors in one or more sample data impexes in the `sapbusinessagreementaddon` extension, try importing them manually one by one (from hac), and see which one crashes

Update :

Seems *zh_CN* language is missing from your database, try creating it using the following :

```
INSERT_UPDATE Language;isocode[unique=true];active[default=true]
 ;zh_CN;
```

Adapt this code to correspond more to your needs

Comment: Hello, i tried to import the impex manually through HAC. All impex were successfully imported. There was no issue with impex file. So what could be the cause of this issue then? @B.M